# Check if a list is part of another list while preserving the list sequence

Tags: python, list

How to check if a list in python is part of another list with preserving the order. Example:

```py
a = [3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
b = [4, 1, 2]
Answer is True

a = [3, 4, 1, 0, 2, 5]
b = [4, 1, 2]
Answer is False as the order is not matched
```

Comment: If you're interested in learning it, KMP is applicable here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth–Morris–Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using python lists equality, comparing the sublists at all positions:

```
is_b_sublist_of_a = any(b == a[i:i+len(b)] for i in range(len(a)))
```

The expression `a[i:i+len(b)]` creates a list at the length of `b` starting from the `i`th position. This expression is computed for all positions in `a`. If any of the comparisons return `True`, the `any` expression will be `True` as well, and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
def is_a_in_x(A, X):
  for i in range(len(X) - len(A) + 1):
    if A == X[i:i+len(A)]: return True
  return False
```