# Check if List is part of List keeping order and find postion

Tags: python, list, match

I need to seek the "matchingpoint" of two list where List "a" is bigger than List "b".
So far I've found this earlier post:
[Check if a list is part of another list while preserving the list sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58351501/check-if-a-list-is-part-of-another-list-while-preserving-the-list-sequence)

That helps a lot. But I need to now, where the lists fit.

```
a = [3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5]
b = [4, 1, 2]
```

"b" fits in "a" but instead of a `TRUE` value I would like to have `a[1]` as first matchingpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to fetch the first *matching point*:

```
a = [3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5]
b = [4, 1, 2]

starting_point = next((a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if b == a[i:i + len(b)]), -1)

print(starting_point)
```

**Output**

```
4
```

**UPDATE**

If you need both the index and the value at the index, return the index instead of the value, for example:

```
position = next((i for i in range(len(a)) if b == a[i:i + len(b)]), -1)

print("position", position)
print("starting point", a[position])
```

**Output**

```
position 1
starting point 4
```

Note the change, now is `i` instead of `a[i]`

Comment: Thanks for the fast feedback! If I understand the output correctly `starting_point = 4` is the first Element in `a` that is `4`?

Comment: If added a few lines to get the postion in `a` :  `a = [3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 4, 1, 2]
b = [4, 1, 2]

starting_point = next((a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if b == a[i:i + len(b)]), -1)

position = a.index(starting_point)

print("starting_point =" , starting_point)
print("postion = a[",position,"]") `                                                                                Output:                                                                                                               `starting_point = 4
postion = a[ 1 ]`

Comment: @KaiStredder If you want the position just return i instead of a[i], I added at update to the question.