# Python Vektor or Matrix optimisation

Tags: python, optimization, vector, scipy

In an earlier Post: [Check if List is part of List keeping order and find postion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64907723/check-if-list-is-part-of-list-keeping-order-and-find-postion/64907758?noredirect=1#comment114757156_64907758) I tried to solve my problem via a simple loop. Now I found the sciPy module. And I wonder if that might be the faster solution, since the Vectors are quite big. But since I'm not a native English speaker I'm having problems to figure it out  :-)

The scenario:
I'm trying to find the best timing of starting flexible Loads (ex. Washing machine) to optimize the usage of self produced Solar Energy. I have a Pandas Dataframe with measurement values from the solar panels for each minute of the day and Load Values minute wise for 2hours. That gives me 2 Vektors:

```
v1[x1,x2,x3,...,x4,xn] with n = 1440 ,positive values (solar energy)
v2[x1,x2,x3,...,x4,xn] with n = 120 ,negative values (load)
```

I want to find the spot where

```
v3 + v2 >= 0  with v3 element of v1 and same length as v2
```

Maybe someone has an Idea or a link to a good explanation of how to solve that problem.

Thanks in forward!

Comment: It's unclear but I guess v1 and v2 are timeseries. Reindex v1 values by interpolation on v2 index.

Comment: I know, my description is a bit difficult. You are correct, the data is a timeseries measurement.  And the problem is, that the measured incidents can't be sliced, so the length an position of the data can't be changed (except for filing up v2 with 0 to create the same length of v1). That's why reindexing and interpolation aren't possible.